# 'fastboot reboot' works but not the other fastboot commands

Tags: fastboot, micromax-a350

I know most MediaTek devices don't support fastboot, but I have a Canvas Knight (MT6592) which does reboot into fastboot mode when I use `adb reboot bootloader`.

Here, `fastboot devices` detects my device and `fastboot reboot` reboots it. But if I try:

1. `fastboot oem device-info` : ran for over 10 minutes with no result. I finally stopped it using Ctrl+PsBrk.
2. `fastboot oem get_unlock_state` : ran for 2.24 minutes and ended up with this error:

   ```
   FAILED (status read failed (Too many links))
   ```
3. `fastboot oem device-info` : after (2), this also gives an error imediately:

   ```
   FAILED (command write failed (Too many links))
   ```
4. `fastboot devices` : ??????????????? device
5. `fastboot reboot` :

   ```
   rebooting
   FINISHED: -0.000s
   ```

However, the device doesn't reboot until I force it to using the power button.

Any idea what the problem is? I know that fastboot is unsupported and it may have problems, but if it is unsupported shouldn't it not work at all?

(No problems on the computer end. Same commands on a Nexus 9 work perfectly, and after rebooting the phone fastboot devices and fastboot reboot works, but then again the same problem)

Comment: Also, I later learned that these devices have a very truncated support for fastboot, and I managed to root it anyway.

Comment: Having similar issues... did you manage to find a fix?

Comment: @Warrior, check my previous comment. There isn't a fix unless you hack the bootloader to properly support fastboot. Anyway, Mediatek devices don't support fastboot properly unless it's an Android One, maybe, or in other extremely rare cases. BTW, if you are on 4.4.2, KingRoot can root it.